# How does the React load and execute a JSX contents?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How does it detect the JSX code and process it?

```
<script src="src/main.js" type="text/babel"></script>
```

Comment: Your question is vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React does not detect nor understands JSX at all.

Babel transforms all JSX into function calls. To process content of `<script type="text/babel"></script>` in browser, you have to include Babel itself before.

```
<!-- Load Babel -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
// content here
</script>
```

More info [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation)